# WebEx audio doesn't work on 12.04 LTS 32-bit

Tags: 12.04, sound, 32-bit, webex

I got "The Audio Device is Unaccessible Now" when trying to connect audio to WebEx session using computer. It's known issue for 64-bit installations and common workaround is to setup 32-bit browser and Java. It works, I saw it by myself.
But I got the same issue on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit.

Firefox 16.0.2 (Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0) or Chronium Version 20.0.1132.47 Ubuntu 12.04 (144678) - does not matter.
Java(TM) Plug-in 1.7.0_09.

Java 7 - Oracle 32 bit:
java -version
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)

Does anyone know what could be wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by latest WebEx software update

Comment: You should probably accept your own answer as the best one, as the issue got solved.

Comment: I still have the problem on the latest ubuntu / webex

Answer (score 1):

Last evening I ran in the same trouble. Ubuntu 12.04 with OpenJDK 7. I had no error message but the incoming audio was mute or only working for a few seconds. I figured out that it seems to be a problem with the alsa plugin for java and pulseaudio.
After removing pulseaudio like in these link

http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/01/how-to-remove-pulseaudio-use-alsa-ubuntu-linux/

it worked fine.

Maybe these topics are related with this problem

http://pl.digipedia.org/usenet/thread/11149/13875/

but this is far above my understanding.

Hope this helps, Tobias

Comment: two additional links: http://www.mail-archive.com/pulseaudio-discuss@lists.freedesktop.org/msg03977.html http://www.mentby.com/matthew-gregan/immediate-underrun-with-pulseaudio-alsa-plugin-when-pa-and-alsa-buffer-sizes-differ.html

Comment: I don't think this is the same problem.

Comment: if you do remove pulseaudio I imagine you'll break all sorts of useful things, such as having two apps playing sound at once.