# Webex sound hangs in audio conference mode

Tags: 12.04, sound, webex

When I join webex meeting sound hangs periodically so I have to restart my X session relog-in  webex meeting to make it works again in meeting (ubuntu 12.04 32bit). It would be great if someone suggests better solution for sound hangs in webex. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed that pulseaudio (precisely the communication between pulseaudio and alsa) causes the problem. And the solution is to remove pulseaudio and use alsa audio server directly. You can refer to below link and give it a try. I've it done today but don't yet have a webex meeting chance to confirm if it works. Good luck.

[WebEx audio doesn't work on 12.04 LTS 32-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217578/webex-audio-doesnt-work-on-12-04-lts-32-bit)